Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 11 for '{{node functional_3_1/ctc_1/Squeeze}} = Squeeze[T=DT_INT32,
i have been trying to train a model on extracting handwritten text from images . for this i have been using a hybrd model , where i am using Resnet model for features extraction and lstm for handling sequences .but for doing the same , i am facing error and i am not able to fix it  .
this is my error image 
here is my detailed code.
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Lambda, Bidirectional, LSTM, Dropout, Reshape, Concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
import cv2
import os
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Step 1: Character Mapping
characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
char_to_num = {char: i for i, char in enumerate(characters)}
num_classes = len(characters) + 1  # Include blank label for CTC
max_text_length = 11  # Adjust based on your dataset

# Step 2: Image Preprocessing Function
def load_and_process_image(image_path, img_height=32, img_width=256):
    img = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (img_width, img_height))
    img = img.astype('float32') / 255.0
    img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=-1)  # Add channel dimension
    return img

# Step 3: Convert Text to Sequence
def text_to_sequence(text, char_to_num):
    return [char_to_num[char] for char in text if char in char_to_num]

# Step 4: Load Dataset
def load_dataset(image_dir, label_dir, char_to_num, max_text_length, img_height=32, img_width=256):
    image_data = []
    label_data = []
    label_lengths = []

    for img_file in os.listdir(image_dir):
        if img_file.endswith(".png") or img_file.endswith(".jpg"):
            img_path = os.path.join(image_dir, img_file)
            image = load_and_process_image(img_path, img_height, img_width)
            image_data.append(image)

            label_file = img_file.replace(".png", ".txt").replace(".jpg", ".txt")
            label_path = os.path.join(label_dir, label_file)

            with open(label_path, 'r') as f:
                text = f.readline().strip()

            sequence = text_to_sequence(text, char_to_num)
            label_length = len(sequence)
            padded_sequence = pad_sequences([sequence], maxlen=max_text_length, padding='post')[0]
            label_data.append(padded_sequence)
            label_lengths.append(label_length)  # Store actual label length before padding

    image_data = np.array(image_data, dtype=np.float32)
    label_data = np.array(label_data, dtype=np.int32)
    label_lengths = np.array(label_lengths, dtype=np.int32)

    return image_data, label_data, label_lengths

# Step 5: Build the Model
def build_resnet_feature_extractor(input_shape):
    base_model = ResNet50(include_top=False, input_shape=input_shape)
    return Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=base_model.output)

def build_bilstm_layer(feature_extractor_output, lstm_units=256):
    lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(lstm_units, return_sequences=True))(feature_extractor_output)
    lstm = Dropout(0.25)(lstm)
    return lstm

def apply_attention_layer(lstm_output):
    attention = tf.keras.layers.Attention()([lstm_output, lstm_output])
    return attention

def ctc_loss_lambda_func(args):
    labels, y_pred, input_length, label_length = args
    labels = tf.cast(labels, dtype=tf.int32)
    input_length = tf.cast(input_length, dtype=tf.int32)
    label_length = tf.cast(label_length, dtype=tf.int32)
    
    # Ensure label_length is squeezed to the expected shape
    label_length = tf.squeeze(label_length, axis=-1)  # Squeeze to ensure it's 1D

    return tf.keras.backend.ctc_batch_cost(labels, y_pred, input_length, label_length)

def build_ctc_loss_model(inputs, outputs, max_text_length):
    labels = Input(shape=(max_text_length,), name='labels')
    input_length = Input(shape=(1,), name='input_length')
    label_length = Input(shape=(1,), name='label_length')
    ctc_loss = Lambda(ctc_loss_lambda_func, output_shape=(1,), name='ctc')([labels, outputs, input_length, label_length])
    return Model(inputs=[inputs, labels, input_length, label_length], outputs=ctc_loss)

def build_handwriting_ocr_model(input_shape, max_text_length, lstm_units=256):
    inputs = Input(shape=input_shape, name='image_input')

    # Concatenate the grayscale image to 3 channels
    concatenated = Concatenate()([inputs, inputs, inputs])

    # Feature extraction with ResNet50
    feature_extractor = build_resnet_feature_extractor((input_shape[0], input_shape[1], 3))  # update input to 3 channels
    features = feature_extractor(concatenated)

    # Reshape for LSTM input
    features = Reshape((-1, features.shape[-1]))(features)

    # BiLSTM + Dropout
    lstm_output = build_bilstm_layer(features, lstm_units=lstm_units)

    # Attention Layer
    attention_output = apply_attention_layer(lstm_output)

    # Output Layer
    outputs = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name='output')(attention_output)

    # CTC Loss Model
    ctc_model = build_ctc_loss_model(inputs, outputs, max_text_length)

    return ctc_model

# Step 6: Load Data and Split
image_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/ifsc_croped'
label_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/ifsc_cropped_txt'

train_images, train_labels, train_label_lengths = load_dataset(image_dir, label_dir, char_to_num, max_text_length)
train_images, val_images, train_labels, val_labels, train_label_lengths, val_label_lengths = train_test_split(
    train_images, train_labels, train_label_lengths, test_size=0.2, random_state=42
)

# Step 7: Padding Function
def pad_labels(label_sequences, max_text_length):
    return pad_sequences(label_sequences, maxlen=max_text_length, padding='post')

# Step 8: Data Generator
def data_generator(images, labels, label_lengths, batch_size, max_text_length):
    downsample_factor = 8  # Adjust based on your model
    time_steps = images.shape[2] // downsample_factor

    while True:
        for i in range(0, len(images), batch_size):
            batch_images = images[i:i + batch_size]
            batch_labels = labels[i:i + batch_size]
            batch_label_lengths = label_lengths[i:i + batch_size]

            input_lengths = np.ones((len(batch_images), 1), dtype=np.int32) * time_steps
            label_lengths_batch = np.array(batch_label_lengths, dtype=np.int32).reshape(-1, 1)  # Ensure shape is (batch_size, 1)

            inputs = {
                'image_input': batch_images,
                'labels': batch_labels,
                'input_length': input_lengths,
                'label_length': label_lengths_batch
            }

            outputs = np.zeros((len(batch_images), 1))  # Dummy outputs for CTC

            yield (inputs, outputs)

# Step 9: Compile and Train the Model
input_shape = (32, 256, 1)  # Adjust according to your images
model = build_handwriting_ocr_model(input_shape, max_text_length)
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam())

# Define training parameters
batch_size = 32
epochs = 20

history = model.fit(
    data_generator(train_images, train_labels, train_label_lengths, batch_size, max_text_length),
    validation_data=data_generator(val_images, val_labels, val_label_lengths, batch_size, max_text_length),
    steps_per_epoch=len(train_images) // batch_size,
    validation_steps=len(val_images) // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs
)


